# determine html/xml node inconsistency XPath, HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

How to determine which node is broken?
I use asp.net, C Sharp, XPath, HtmlAgility Pack.

For example - the closing "<\book" tag is missing ">":

```
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book

</bookstore>
```

Another example - the closing <\title> tag is missing:

```
<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

So, when I use CS, HtmlAgility & XPath like:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;
root.SelectNodes("//book")
//or
root.SelectNodes("//book/title")
```

I want to determine which node is 'broken', and do something to fix the node.

I want to use csharp/asp.net from codebehind for this solution (not xsl/xslt example). Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: @user569008: You should catch such errors in parsing stage. Any XML parser would complain about a ilegal character in name or some thing because the `</book </bookstore>` end tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack fixes errors by itself. 
So situations provided by you are processed correctly in HtmlDocument.LoadHtml method. 
For example this xml `<bookstore><title><book>sssss</title</bookstore>` will be treated as `<bookstore><title><book>sssss</book></title></bookstore>`.

But after document loading  you could check out `doc.ParseErrors` collection to analyze some errors. Also you should take into account that missing closed tag (`<book><title>ssss</book>`) isn't error and missing ">" is.

**Upd**

1) Missed closing tag isn't error. Broken tag is error.

2) Load and LoadHtml have the same behaviours.

Comment: Can you tell me what is considered as error and what is not? For example: </titl, <title> (missing closing '/'), /title>. What is considered to be a missing closed tag?

Comment: Is there any meaning for my question if I use Load or LoadHtml method? Meaning = fixes errors by itself.